# What is the default maximum length of html input \ text area?

Tags: css, html, input

What is the default maximum length of html input fields in a form  and  text area?
is it limited at all?

Comment: Unlimited, see [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) maxLength attribute

Answer (score 7):

When there is no max length specified the default is an unlimited number of characters for both textarea and text input.

From the MDN web docs for textarea,

> The maximum number of characters (unicode code points) that the user can enter. If this value isn't specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. [MDN Web Docs Textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

for text input

> If no maxlength is specified, or an invalid value is specified, the text input has no maximum length. [MDN Web Docs Text Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)

Answer (score 3):

If no `maxlength` attribute is specified, then there is no limit to how much text a user can enter. This is the same for a [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) input or a [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

Answer (score 1):

It seems Safari imposes a limit on text type input fields (100,000 characters I believe), but not on textareas.